# Android ListView row padding/margin

Tags: android, xml, listview, height, divider

I have a problem with my Android listview. My list uses a custom arrayadapter, that sets an onClickListener for the message image and the list has an onItemClickListener. It all works fine, but as you can see in the screenshot below, the image doesn't fill it's parent. 
So when I click above, below or to the right of the image the onItemClickListener is called.

My wish is to completely divide the row in two sections. And I believe the solution to this lies in the row.xml or the xml for the ListView. How can i fill the entire row with my image?

[The Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Hij.png)

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
android:id="@+id/row2">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logominimini" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
</LinearLayout>
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/divider"
         android:layout_width="3dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/divider_background"
         android:visibility="gone"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selectmessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/messageunselected" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Listview:

```
   <ListView 
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:fastScrollEnabled="true" 
android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_background" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the commented property `android:padding="6dip"`, put it in ImageView or elsewhere but not in parent `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
<!-- remove this: android:padding="6dip" -->
android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
android:id="@+id/row2">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logominimini" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
</LinearLayout>
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/divider"
         android:layout_width="3dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/divider_background"
         android:visibility="gone"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selectmessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/messageunselected" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had missed that detail since i got the layout from an example. Here is the result, as I wanted it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24622131/device-2011-12-16-124434.png

Answer (score 0):

Which image you want to fill the entire row **First image or Last image** ?

For both ImageViews you kept padding, then how those can fill parent ??

Please check your code once and your question also not clear.

I saw you screenshot and the i thought you are talking about second image view.

If so, then remove padding in ImageView.

I think it will help you.